# how to use tidyverse's mutate function to create multiple columns by a self defined function

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(6,7,8))
```

I want to add two columns of the distance from mean of a:

| a | b | diff_a | diff_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | -1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 | 4 |

I don't want to write columns separately in mutate, as it will calculate *mean* multiple times(mean is example here, I actually have a functions takes a lot time). I want to use one function like

```
calculates <- function(a, b){
  e_a <- mean(a)
  return list(a - e_a, b - e_a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We many need

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Meana = mean(a), across(a:b, 
        ~ . - Meana, .names = "diff_{.col}"), Meana = NULL)
```

-output

```
  a b diff_a diff_b
1 1 4     -1      2
2 2 5      0      3
3 3 6      1      4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may return a named list from the function and use `cbind` to add new columns to the dataframe.

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))

calculates <- function(a, b){
  e_a <- mean(a)
  return(list(diff_a = a - e_a, diff_b = b - e_a))
}

cbind(df, calculates(df$a, df$b))

#  a b diff_a diff_b
#1 1 4     -1      2
#2 2 5      0      3
#3 3 6      1      4
```